# How to retrieve integer values from a comma separated string array which is stored in a session?

Tags: c#, session, model-view-controller

I have a string array  like this

```
string[] BranchIds = {"1","2","3"};
```

and then stored it into a session

```
Session["BranchIds"] = BranchIds;
```

Now how can I retrieve this values as integers from session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string[] branchIds = (string[])Session["BranchIds"]
```

Then you can iterate array for it's values.

Comment: The OP said they wanted the values as `int`

Answer (score 1):

You first get the values as an array of strings:

`var strArr = (string[])Session["BranchIds"];`

Then you can convert it to an array of int:

`var intArr = Array.ConvertAll(strArr, int.Parse);`

Answer (score 1):

The 2 Question are not related, so retrieve from session is same as you add to session so if say:

```
string [] BranchIds = (string[])Session["BranchIds"]
```

then you you retrieved the array from session.

to parse a string value to integer you can use:

```
Int32.Parse()
```

so for example to parse first id:

```
int id = Int32.Parse(BranchIds[0]);
```

or you can do a for loop and convert all of them to integers, or you can store to session in integer from beginning if needed.

Comment: Thanks!!How to trim this elements before adding ?